# Eclipse Reads from a different class(file)

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration

This problem continues to persist and I am hoping that someone who understands Eclipse can help.
Previously, I worked on a project that involved reading files. However, I am complete with that project and now my current project keeps reading the previous file.

I just want to run programs seperate from the personalityy.java file

I have already tried run -> configuration

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3I9TI.jpg)
It reads from personalityy.java

Comment: This sounds like maybe your build is simply out of date.

Comment: can you clarify or how can I change this?

Comment: i actually have build automatically set... this is still not working for me!

Comment: I can't fix your problem without sitting down at your computer.  Try searching Stack Overflow.

Comment: Are you sure you are running the right file? If you right click on miniGap.java and select "run as->java application", do you get the same output?

Comment: yeah even with java application too its reading from the personalittyy.java file...

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty unclear about what exactly you're trying to do, but in short, to run a java application, right-click on the source file in the explorer and select "Run As" and "Java Application".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are new to Eclipse. Don't worry the problem is pretty simple. The Green run button on the menu bar will run the last run program by default. You probably have the new file open and you are using the run button in the menu to run. What you have to do is.

1. Open the file you want to run.
2. Right click inside the new file in text editor
3. Click Run as
4. Click Java Application.

In the future you can click the black down arrow beside the run button to select which program you want to run.